# Will Google Firebase Hosting support .NET core application?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Will Google Firebase support .NET core application? How to find the list of programming language supported by google firebase.

I couldn't find any information related to the supported programming language in their official site: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/

Update 1:
* We can use Node.js and Express App

Comment: I am professional .net developer. I am looking for better cloud hosting for .net applications. That's why.

Answer (score 10):

Firebase Hosting is a static hosting solution that also offers integration with Google Cloud Functions. Firebase Hosting will support whatever languages are supported by Cloud Functions, which is currently only Node.js.

It is unlikely that .NET Core will be supported any time in the near future, if at all.

Comment: Micheal, but we can host Node.js and Express App

Comment: Correct, you can host Node.js apps by [rewriting URLs to a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions).

Answer (score 1):

Firebase can be used with IOS, Android, C++, unity, and web according to this page:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/

If you want to use `.net`

then you can use [Firebase Rest API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/)

Also check those:

https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet

https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp

Answer (score 0):

You can host only static applications in firebase like Agular, React and normal HTML pages with CSS and javascript. If you are looking from any framework from Microsoft then you can host Blazor apps in firebase.